# Apache2 server does not start cannot pen shared object file

Tags: apache-2.2, phusion-passenger

I am working with Apache and Passenger for a Rails project. And a during a restart I got the following error

> `Cannot load /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/passenger-2.2.11/ext/apache2/mod_passenger.so into` `server: /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/passenger-2.2.11/ext/apache2/mod_passenger.so: cannot` `open shared object file: No such file or directory`

However there is no change in the apache configuration file. I have attached the snippet from the conf file

> `287 LoadModule passenger_module /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/passenger-2.2.11/ext/apache2/mod_passenger.so`
>
> `288 PassengerRoot /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/passenger-2.2.11`
>
> `289 PassengerRuby /usr/bin/ruby1.8`

I am also unable to locate the shared object file in the location pointed to by the server though I am not really sure how the .so file is works (created/destroyed)

I would also appreciate it if someone could explain to me what exactly has happened. I understand the shared object file is mission, what could be the reason it got deleted.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you don't have it installed.

$ sudo passenger-install-apache2-module

You need to run that so that the apache mod_passenger.so can be compiled after installing the gem (gem install passenger)

And take a look at the output presented by the installer. It will show you where the files are. In fact, it shows you exactly how the configuration must look.

Answer (score 3):

try

```
locate mod_passenger.so
```

or if that doesn't work issue

```
find / -type f -name mod_passenger.so
```

if that doesn't return anything that means you don't have it installed.